# Cut steel fascia board cover lengthwise?

Tags: trim, soffit, fascia

I am wrapping a porch beam with white steel fascia board cover. The height of the space I need to cover is about an inch less than what the fascia board cover is. So I need to basically cut an inch off the entire length of steel for this beam. It's about 28 linear feet of material.

I am afraid using tin snips would crinkle the material.  I am thinking of a cutting disc on an angle grinder but that's going to make a heck of a mess and brings in potential for not getting a straight cut. A skill saw with a carbon blade would mar the paint in a heart beat, it seems like it's so easy to scratch. Any other ideas I have not considered?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what sort of edge treatment you need at the top, but fascia and other light sheet steel can be cut with a sharp utility knife.

With clamps or a helper, lay a straightedge on the back side of the fascia and score along it with a new knife blade. Knife angle is important and can cause your cut to run astray. Keep things in line. Run the cut twice more, then remove the straightedge and snap the metal along the cut by flexing it.

If it doesn't fold on the snap right away, and cleanly, score the metal again with the knife. You only need to get maybe halfway through the metal for it to snap.

If you know someone in the siding or HVAC business with a [brake apparatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brake_(sheet_metal_bending)), cut your metal a bit wide and have them hem it to the final height. A hem provides a safer workpiece and a nicer finish.